# WPF: Individual Style for elements

Tags: .net, wpf, styles

C#

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public Color MyColor { get; set; }
}
```

WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="my:MyButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CheckBox Content="Individual Mode" x:Name="ModeCheckBox" Grid.Row="0" />
        <my:MyButton Content="B1" x:Name="myB1" Grid.Row="1" MyColor="Aqua"/>
        <my:MyButton Content="B2" x:Name="myB2" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <my:MyButton Content="B3" x:Name="myB3" Grid.Row="3" MyColor="Green"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now. 
I want all my buttons be blue (this is normal mode), and specific individual "MyColor" for each button (this is individual mode).

Is it possible?

Once I try to set a style element (the `Background` in my case) by code, I broke the style logic and it does not switch back anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal mode" / "individual mode"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a default style for the `MyButton` control; which will be stored in the `Themes/Generic.xaml` file.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="MyColor" Value="Blue"/>
    </Style>
```

That button now by default will have the `MyColor` property set to `Blue` unless explicitly specified otherwise on each control instance.

```
    <Grid>
        <local:MyButton Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top">MyButtonDefault</local:MyButton>
        <local:MyButton Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" MyColor="Red">MyButtonRed</local:MyButton>
    </Grid>
```

Below is the `MyButton` source where I am changing the `Background` property for this example based on the `MyColor` property.

```
    public class MyButton : Button
    {
        static MyButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButton)));
        }

        public Color MyColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(MyColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyColorProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MyButton), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(Change)));

         private static void Change(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyButton element = target as MyButton;
            element.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)e.NewValue);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

To reset the color back to the default value simply call `ClearValue(DependencyProperty)` on the `MyButton` instance.

```
    private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyButton myButton = sender as MyButton;
        myButton.ClearValue(MyButton.MyColorProperty);
    }
```

Comment: once MyColor changed, ho to reset it back to blue?

Comment: @serhio Added additional information at the bottom of the answer

Comment: What it the sense of the static constructor? I tried without, and it worked as well.

Comment: @serhio The constructor is used to override the default Type; in this case we are setting the Type to MyButton. When the framework searches Generic.xaml it will look for that Type as the Type when applying the style.

Comment: in fact, I had a look for the themes, does this feature supports the UserControls as well as CustomControls? because the mine is a UserControl... or, perhaps, should i change my UserControl be a CustomControl...

Comment: @Aaron: tryed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153708/wpf-converting-from-usercontrol-to-customcontrol but I think i will renounce, because of private elements. This is impossible to obtain private elements of a template from the beginning (constructor)

Comment: @serhio My code above is a custom control...take that and port over your specifics. Should be fairly trivial.

Comment: @Aaron: I think to use it with a UserControl, where I'll be able to use the XAML elements in .cs code.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.Window2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="my:MyButton">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ModeCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MyColor}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ModeCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CheckBox Content="Individual Mode" x:Name="ModeCheckBox" Grid.Row="0" />
    <my:MyButton Content="B1" x:Name="myB1" Grid.Row="1" MyColor="Red"/>
    <my:MyButton Content="B2" x:Name="myB2" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <my:MyButton Content="B3" x:Name="myB3" Grid.Row="3" MyColor="Green"/>

</Grid>

</Window>
```

I also changed the MyButton class:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public Brush MyColor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Individual mode, means individual mode - each button have an individual color - MyColor color. B1 is Aqua and b3 is Green. In the non-individual mode, all buttons are the same.

Comment: Ahh - I missed a few details.  I went ahead and updated my sample.

Comment: It worked in my code...  I'm using VS 2008 / .NET framework 3.5 - what are you using?  Also note that I changed it to type Brush to match up with the Background property of the button.