# WPF: Converting from UserControl to CustomControl

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a WPF `UserControl` - `SegmentConrol`, that represents a line with some text and an array displaying the direction (>).

As I have to customize this control styles, I decided to switch to a CustomControl, because I read this is better in a way...

Now, I have some "troubles" to switch from UC to CC.

Particularly, no idea **where to put the `<UserControl.Resources>` part.**

If any of experts could advise me they are welcomed.

Here is my UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.ctlWpfPlanDeLigne.SegmentControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ctlWpfPlanDeLigne"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="ParentSegmentControl">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
        <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <local:SegmentToStringConverter x:Key="SegmentToStringConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Canvas Background="Transparent">
        <Line x:Name="line"              
              X1="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=X1}"
              Y1="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=Y1}"
              X2="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=X2}"
              Y2="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=Y2}"  IsHitTestVisible="True"/>

        <Label x:Name="label" 
               Foreground="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=LabelForeground}" 
               Background="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=LabelBackground}"
               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=IsLabelUsed, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
               >
            <Label.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Color="White" Opacity="1" RenderingBias="Performance" ShadowDepth="0" />
            </Label.Effect>
        </Label>
        <Polygon Name="arrow" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=IsArrowUsed, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Bellow, is the `Themes/Generic.xaml` file of the new CustomControl I refactor the old UserControl:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ctlWpfPlanDeLigne">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SegmentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SegmentControl}">
                    <Canvas Background="Transparent">
                        <Line x:Name="line"...

                        <Label x:Name="label"...
                        <Polygon x:Name="arrow" ...
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

## Edit:

What to do with the code

```
    public SegmentControl()
    {
        this.line.StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Round;
        this.arrow.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
        this.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    }
```

when `this.line` or `this.arrow` is not defined? Thanks.

## EDIT 2

Generic.XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SegmentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SegmentControl}">
                <Canvas Background="Transparent">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    </Border>
                    <Line x:Name="PART_line"
                          X1="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=X1}"
                          Y1="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=Y1}"
                          X2="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=X2}"
                          Y2="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=Y2}"
                          IsHitTestVisible="True"/>

                    <Label x:Name="PART_label"
                           Foreground="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=LabelForeground}"
                           Background="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=LabelBackground}"
                           Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=IsLabelUsed, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <Label.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Color="White" Opacity="1" RenderingBias="Performance" ShadowDepth="0" />
                        </Label.Effect>
                    </Label>
                    <Polygon x:Name="PART_arrow" 
                             Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ParentSegmentControl, Path=IsArrowUsed, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

.cs:

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        this.line = this.FindName("PART_line") as Line;      // null
        this.arrow = this.FindName("PART_arrow") as Polygon; // null
        this.label = this.FindName("PART_label") as Label;   // null

        this.line.StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Round;
        this.arrow.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why you can't just put them straight into the resource dictionary? They can then be re-used by other styles/templates..

```
 <ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ctlWpfPlanDeLigne">

            <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
            <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
            <local:SegmentToStringConverter x:Key="SegmentToStringConverter"/>

    <Style....
```

**EDIT:**

In response to your second question, you will need to do this in code:

```
Line line = this.FindName("line") as Line;
Polygon arrow = this.FindName("arrow") as Polygon;
```

Although it's common practice to name your controls with "PART_" so it reads

```
Line line = this.FindName("PART_line") as Line;
Polygon arrow = this.FindName("PART_arrow") as Polygon;
```

This name corresponds to the x:Name given in the xaml..

**EDIT 3:**

You'll need to make sure your window knows about your resource dictionary like this:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Namespace.Controls;component/Themes/CustomControls.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </WindowResources>
```

Comment: thank you. I have a little edit that I don't understand. Thanks by advance.

Comment: @serhio I've updated my answer to answer your second question

Comment: @David: So, I can declare private Line line; obtain it in constructor, and use it in the code like an UserControl does.

Comment: @Serhio: Actually not sure if it will work in the constructor. You might have to obtain them in the OnApplyTemplate method which you can override.

Comment: @DavidMasters84: I confirm, in the constructor it returns "null". But what if that elements where used *before* ApplyTemplate

Comment: ( it generates me a lot of troubles (bugs), because private elements are not initialized yet (null) in the code I use... apparently "OnApplyTemplate" is called too late...

Comment: Not sure what to suggest other than to restructure your code so that those parts aren't used until after the template is applied (which I think is how it should be anyway)

Comment: Hmm I don't see why that wouldn't work. The only thing I can think of is that you haven't added your ResourceDictionary to the Window's resources. I'll edit my answer to show you how to do that.

Comment: I think I found the "error", the code should be like this: `this.line = this.Template.FindName("PART_line", this) as Line;`

Comment: Ah ha! Yeah that's probably it :)

Comment: finally, the code runs without exception, but I lost all the customization, because of the code of dependency properties like `static void OnFillChanged(source, e){ if (source.line != null) source.line.Fill = (Brush)e.NewValue; }` that does not work because is applyed before template changed... ufff ) thanks however! )

Answer (score 1):

Also note that you have to add

```
    static SegmentControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SegmentControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SegmentControl)));
    }
```

to `SegmentControl` in order to apply the default theme without specifying the style directly.